# Reading binary file (.chn) in Python

Tags: python, file-io, binary

In python, how do I read a binary file (here I need to read a .chn file) and show the result in binary format?

Comment: What do you consider "binary format"?

Comment: binary format : 0000000 1111111, and i will convert it into hexadecimal after that

Comment: So are the values separated by a space?

Comment: @rubik : i dont know exactly it has space in between or not. i don't really know how the format of .chn file is.

Comment: @Smith: How can we propose a solution without knowing the format?

Comment: I Googled that and it seems to be an Ethnograph Data File. Can you provide a simple example (if you have one)?

Comment: @rubik : I have just been asked to show the result in binary format. and i never worked using python before.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Python 3 I presume.

Comment: its depends on which library i want to use. if i use 'Tkinter', i will use python 3.2 and if i use 'Wx' i will use python 2.7. but now im using python 3.2. For the example that you asked for, i will provide in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that values are separated by a space:

```
with open('myfile.chn', 'rb') as f:
    data = []
    for line in f:  # a file supports direct iteration
        data.extend(hex(int(x, 2)) for x in line.split())
```

In Python is better to use `open()` over `file()`, documentation says it explicitly:

> When opening a file, it’s preferable to use open() instead of invoking
>   the file constructor directly.

`rb` mode will open the file in binary mode.

Reference:
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

Comment: +1: for opening the file in binary-mode. Nitpick: I would have used binascii.hexlify.

Comment: it has error : invalid literal for int() with base 2: b'\xff\xff\x01\x00\x01\x0056I\xecO\x00\xcc/K\x0018MAR11'

Comment: @mirk: Yes, that's a good idea. I'll edit as soon as possible.

Comment: @Smith: Can't you just post a piece of that file? Just to get an idea of its structure...

Comment: i have the picture of the file (.png),but i dont know how to show you.

Comment: FF FF 01 00 01 00 35 36 49 EC 4F 00 CC 2F 4B 00 31 38 4D 41 52 31 31 20 30 34 32 31 00

Comment: this is one line complete but in hexadecimal

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    with open('myfile.chn') as f:
        data=f.read()
        data=[bin(ord(x)).strip('0b') for x in data]
        print ''.join(data)
```

and if you want only the binary data it will be in the list.

```
    with open('myfile.chn') as f:
        data=f.read()
        data=[bin(ord(x)).strip('0b') for x in data]
        print data
```

In data now you will have the list of binary numbers. you can take this and convert to hexadecimal number

Comment: Oops that is not 'a' it is 'data'. Now i have edited now check it

Comment: @Smith can you do me a favour

Comment: if you accept the answer it ll increase my rep that's it. Because i need to upvote a question but i am not able to do it without reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
with file('myfile.chn') as f:
  data = f.read()   # read all strings at once and return as a list of strings
  data = [hex(int(x, 2)) for x in data]  # convert to a list of hex strings (by interim getting the decimal value)
```